# Timeout error in "simple" code

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following statement:

There are two type of commands:

`store` `email_content` `urgency`, where `email_content` is a String consisting of [a-zA-Z0-9_] and `urgency` is a positive integer

`get_next_email` - a request that expects `email_content` with highest urgency as a response. If there are 1+ emails with same urgency, output the one that was stored first. If there are no outstanding emails print "-1" string on a newline.

Input example:

```
4
store email1 1
store email2 10
store email3 10
get_next_email
```

Output:

```
email2
```

My code:

```
emails = {}
urgencies = set()
for _ in range(int(input())):
  info = input().strip().split(" ")

  if info[0] == "store":
    info[2] = int(info[2])
    urgencies.add(info[2])
    if info[2] in emails:
        emails[info[2]].append(info[1])
    else:
        emails[info[2]] = [info[1]]

  elif info[0] == "get_next_email":
    if emails:
      maxval = max(urgencies)
      print(emails[maxval].pop(0))
      if emails[maxval] == []:
        emails.pop(maxval, None)
        urgencies.remove(maxval)
    else:
      print("-1")
```

I get a runtime error, which according to what I've read is a consecuence of the compexity being very big, and I don't think my code is *that* complex. What am I doing wrong? And what can I do to improve this? Thanks!

EDIT: It's a contest, the exact error is: Terminated due to timeout (10s)

Comment: What's the exact error you get?

Comment: `O(n)` _doesn't_ tell you anything about the time an algorithm may take to complete.

Comment: I edited the post, sorry for not being specific enough. It's a contest/online challenge and the exact error is "Terminated due to timeout 10s"

Comment: What do you mean, O(n)? This looks at least quadratic to me. Why do you think this is O(n)?

Comment: ```max(urgencies)``` will be one of the slowest parts here (depending on the size of urgencies), as a set is very slow to iterate and not ordered, so that you need linear-iteration.

Comment: Considering that an input consisting of a sequence of `store`s followed by that many `get_next_email`s is basically a sort, you should be very wary of thinking you've gotten it in O(n). O(n) sorting is only possible under very specific assumptions and constraints.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improvement of working code belongs on CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: First, the code is quadratic: for each of **N** *get* commands, you have to search the max of **M** emails.  Also, the combined insertion and sort process of **M** emails is currently quadratic, and **M log M** at best.

Comment: What efficiency testing have *you* done on this?  The only evidence you provide is a failure message from the submission checker.  What input quantity limits do you have from the contest specifications?

Comment: I haven't done any efficiency testing yet. As for the quantity limits, 1 < # urgencies < 10e5, and # commands < 7*10e5